# Is a transformation inappropriate here because of the quadratic pattern in the data?

Tags: regression, data-transformation

Say you're given the following data:

> Time  Yield
>
> 16    2508
>
> 18    2518
>
> 20    3304
>
> 22    3423
>
> 24    3057
>
> 26    3190
>
> 28    3500
>
> 30    3883
>
> 32    3823
>
> 34    3646
>
> 36    3708
>
> 38    3333
>
> 40    3517
>
> 42    3241
>
> 44    3103
>
> 46    2776

[image: data]
Now, the data is about the time until you harvest rice in a paddy; this data looks like it has a quadratic trend. Should I transform it? Why is\isn't a transformation appropriate?

I suspect a transformation is not appropriate because the longer you leave the rice in the paddy, the more likely we lose some rice to animals, rot, or otherwise. Is this a correct suspicion?

Comment: Under what conditions do you think transformation is appropriate/justified? Or why do you think that the loss to animals should influence this decision?

Comment: I don't think it is justified and that's my argument—the yield should go up from time 0 but it MUST have an inflection point given, at the very least, decay. Isn't that justifiable? 

I still see the argument that a linear fit can be achieved with a transformation, but I think that breaks the first rule of our assumptions for linear regression, and that's that we'd suspect a linear fit to be appropriate.

Comment: I think I see the source of confusion. 1) Transformation need not - and a reasonable one would not - get rid of the apparent quadratic shape. Plot log(Yield) ~ Time and take a look. And 2) whether you transform is not related to whether you fit a straight line, or a quadratic shape, or anything else.

Comment: Okay, I concluded this too, I tried tons of transformations that were 'reasonable' and I couldn't get rid of it to any reasonable degree. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Transformation need not - and a reasonable one would not - get rid of the apparent quadratic shape. You will see this if you plot log(Yield) ~ Time.

2) Whether you transform is not strongly related to whether you fit a straight line, or a quadratic shape, or any other shape (with some exceptions e.g. it is not uncommon to log-transform exponential curves to change the problem to a linear regression).

3) Whether you transform should depend on the nature of the data and model you are interested in. In the example above, I do not see any obvious sign that a transformation would be helpful. If you don't need to make a change, then staying on the same scale has the obvious benefit of keeping model coefficients easy to interpret.

Comment: Thank you very much. I asked this problem because there is a great intuition behind why you would not need a transformation (part 3 of what you wrote), but I had the impression that a transformation would not be a bad idea because of examples I thought of (part 2 that you wrote). Anyways, thank you for your concise answer. Once I get enough rep I'll upvote ya.

Comment: @ThomasDevine You're welcome! Happy to help - and welcome to the site!